# How to dual boot my laptop with Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, system-installation

I have some important files and software in my HP Windows notebook. How can I get Ubuntu to dual boot in my notebook without loosing any data?

Answer (score 0):

Just boot your PC with the Ubuntu 14.04 DVD and follow the installer instructions. The section you are asking of is the disk preparation step - there is an option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" - choose it, and installer will automatically shrink Windows partition to make room for Ubuntu.

See [Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) for details; point 4 refers to allocate drive space for Ubuntu, but it is good idea to read the whole document before doing Ubuntu installation.